# Querying Historical Data to get Month End Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a `history` table that keeps all instances of a record, and flags which is the current record and when it is changed - here is a cut down version for it

```
CREATE TABLE *schema*.hist_temp
(
  record_id VARCHAR
  ,record_created_date DATE
  ,current_flag BOOLEAN 
  ,value int
)

INSERT INTO hist_temp VALUES ('Record A','2018-06-01',1,1000);
INSERT INTO hist_temp VALUES ('Record A','2018-04-12',0,900);
INSERT INTO hist_temp VALUES ('Record A','2018-03-13',0,800);
INSERT INTO hist_temp VALUES ('Record A','2018-01-13',0,700);
```

So what we have is Record A, which has been updated 3 times, the latest record is flagged with a 1 but we want to see all 4 instances of the history.

Then we have a `dates` table which holds, among other things, month end dates:

```
    SELECT 
      calendar_date
      ,trunc(month_start) as month_start
    FROM common.calendar
    WHERE
          calendar_year = '2018'
      and calendar_date < trunc(sysdate)
    ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Sample data:

```
calendar_date month_start
2018-06-03    2018-06-01
2018-06-02    2018-06-01
2018-06-01    2018-06-01
2018-05-31    2018-05-01
2018-05-30    2018-05-01
2018-05-29    2018-05-01
2018-05-28    2018-05-01
2018-05-27    2018-05-01
2018-05-26    2018-05-01
2018-05-25    2018-05-01
etc
```

Required results:

I would like to be able to display the following - show the month start / end position for Record A for 2018

```
record_id, month_start, value
 Record A, '2018-06-01', 1000
 Record A, '2018-05-01', 900
 Record A, '2018-04-01', 800
 Record A, '2018-03-01', 700
 Record A, '2018-02-01', 700
```

I am trying to write this query, I have something but know this is wrong as the value is summed up wrongly, please can someone help out ascertain how to get the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
  record_id,
  date_trunc('month', record_created_date)::date AS month_start,
  value
FROM hist_temp
```

Output:

```
Record A    2018-06-01  1000
Record A    2018-04-01  900
Record A    2018-01-01  700
Record A    2018-03-01  800
```